# How to convert this PHP/MYSQL call add_order routine to one with less fields?

Tags: mysql

The textbook version is a call to add order and add the contents of the order from a pre=defined enumeration of non-coffee and coffee products. However I am selling prints, so I don't know how I can properly change the enumeration. Any suggestions?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE add_order (cid INT, uid CHAR(32), ship INT(10), cc MEDIUMINT, OUT total INT(10), OUT oid INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE subtotal INT(10);
    INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, shipping, credit_card_number, order_date) VALUES (cid, ship, cc, NOW());
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO oid;
    INSERT INTO order_contents (order_id, product_type, product_id, quantity, price_per) SELECT oid, c.product_type, c.product_id, c.quantity, IFNULL(sales.price, ncp.price) FROM carts AS c INNER JOIN non_coffee_products AS ncp ON c.product_id=ncp.id LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON (sales.product_id=ncp.id AND sales.product_type='goodies' AND ((NOW() BETWEEN sales.start_date AND sales.end_date) OR (NOW() > sales.start_date AND sales.end_date IS NULL)) ) WHERE c.product_type="goodies" AND c.user_session_id=uid UNION SELECT oid, c.product_type, c.product_id, c.quantity, IFNULL(sales.price, sc.price) FROM carts AS c INNER JOIN specific_coffees AS sc ON c.product_id=sc.id LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON (sales.product_id=sc.id AND sales.product_type='coffee' AND ((NOW() BETWEEN sales.start_date AND sales.end_date) OR (NOW() > sales.start_date AND sales.end_date IS NULL)) ) WHERE c.product_type="coffee" AND c.user_session_id=uid;
    SELECT SUM(quantity*price_per) INTO subtotal FROM order_contents WHERE order_id=oid;
    UPDATE orders SET total = (subtotal + ship) WHERE id=oid;
    SELECT (subtotal + ship) INTO total;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

My fields for the prints (alternate coffee are:

My first successful version is:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE subtotal INT(10);
    INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, shipping, credit_card_number, order_date) VALUES (cid, ship, cc, NOW());
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO oid;

END
```

Here is the table for prints.

[image]
[image: Order Contents]

I also don't have the carts table in my version so with or without the carts table.
[image]

Comment: There is something missing here. At least a reference to the shop you are using (if there are enough users familiar with this shop), or the table structure and some sample data. Otherwise this question is not answerable. The procedure copies data from the cart to orders, if you do not have a cart, it requires a completely different logic of where the products are stored that you want to add to the order (which might be known to users of that shop). Removing the lookup to the coffee-tables (which just adds some product details) is the lesser problem if you provide the table structure.

Comment: Yes, I was writing this question I realized that cart was saved in a `SESSION` in my version but this precedure wouldn't be able to call the session unless it was a mysql datatable `cart` In fact your answer definitely found the root probelm of the transformation .

Comment: My main point was: you need to add the type of your webshop software to your question (probably the title and the tags) to find people that are familiar with it - at least if it is a standard software, and not having a cart is a standard option. This is less a mysql question, but a question specific to this webshop software. For a mysql question, all relevant information is missing (table structure, sample data, expected result, probably the php code and the cart implementation - most of which might be known by someone familiar with the shop software).

Comment: It's not a software just that the source code is specific to the textbook Larry Ullman wrote, one on the MYSQL AND PHP FOr Dynami Websites Version 5 2018 Example Art Store, and the Larry Ullman Effortless Ecommerce Version 2

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood me: your question refers to a book that uses some unknown way to store data and logic around it. Your software uses a different unknown way to store data, tables and logic around it. Your question asks how to transform a procedure that works in the context of the book to a procedure that works in context of your software, without explaining anything about both contexts. This is not answerable for anyone but you. So if you still need help (e.g. if pointing you to the "root problem" was not enough), you would need to add a lot more context or simplify the problem.